# Replace value and duplicate row for each new value

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data frame.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "ID": ["x", "y", "z"],
    "v1": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "v2": ["4", "5", "6"]
})
>>> df
  ID v1 v2
0  x  1  4
1  y  2  5
2  z  3  6
```

I have a dictionary of IDs to replace the IDs in the first column.

```py
>>> id_mapping = {
    "x": ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
    "y": ["id4", "id5"],
    "z": ["id6"]
}
```

In some cases, there is more than one ID to replace the original ID. In those cases I would like to duplicate the rows to create something like this.

```py
>>> new_df
    ID  v1 v2
0  id1   1  4
1  id2   1  4
2  id3   1  4
3  id4   2  5
4  id5   2  5
5  id6   3  6
```

Is there a simple pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `map` and `explode`:

```
print (df.assign(ID=df["ID"].map(id_mapping)).explode("ID")).reset_index(drop=True)

    ID v1 v2
0  id1  1  4
1  id2  1  4
2  id3  1  4
3  id4  2  5
4  id5  2  5
5  id6  3  6
```

Comment: @DanielStandage you can also use [`ignore_index=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) in explode instead of resetting the index.